# Python: use relative Path on multiple machines

Tags: python, opencv, path, virtualenv, relative-path

I have a private PC which i usually use for learning python.
Now I'm on a business trip and i downloaded my project from github to my work pc.

Strucure is:

1. root\
2. root\myScript.py
3. root\images\opencv-logo.png

When I execute my script to show a picture on my private PC, it works just fine.
When I execute the exact same script on my work PC, openCV won't find the file.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

template = cv2.imread("images\\opencv-logo.png")
cv2.imshow("Template", template)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I don't understand why python just doesn't take the relative path from it's execution.
If it would, it would work on every machine in the world ...
Does this have to do with virtual env or something like this?

Errormessage:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Which obviously means it didn't find the picture - which I relate to wrong usage of relative path from the execution location of myScript.py.

Comment: you seem unaware that an executable can sit in some directory, but the *process may run* in another directory. relative paths are resolved relative to the "current working directory" of the process that uses them, not relative to where the executable file is located in the file system.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, even though it does not make more sense to me. If I run myScript.py - then this is my executable, no? I mean how could I know where anyone's python.exe is. That's why I'm trying to do everything within my project folder. So where ever you copy the project folder, relative path will always be the same. That's my struggle right now. How do I solve it?

Comment: it matters *how* you execute something. don't just doubleclick on the script. open a terminal. then you know what the current working directory (CWD) is, because it is shown, and you can start the script, and it will run with that directory as its own CWD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathlib module to handle paths.
For example -

```
from pathlib import Path
import cv2
# here Path('.') means current working directory.
file_path = Path('.') / "images" / "opencv-logo.png" 
# print(file_path.absolute()) # uncomment this to print absolute path
if file_path.exists():
    template = cv2.imread(file_path)
    cv2.imshow("Template", template)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
else:
    print(f"file {file_path} doesn't exists")
```

Comment: Does Path(.) really point to my working directory?
It seems it refers to the PATH Variable instead of the location I execute my file in?

Comment: Got the Code *somewhat* to work, however I get "TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'WindowsPath' to 'str' for 'filename'" ...
Also this seems way too much code for something that should be natively inside this language, no?!
what am I missing...

Comment: @ChrIsso Pathlib treats file paths as path objects. If you're running the file on windows it'll treat it as WindwosPath. If you're running on a different OS it'll be different. Idea, is to treat file paths as objects instead of str so that they can run on any OS.

Comment: good to know - but it doesn't help any beginner at all. I don't know what to do with that information, but thanks i guess?!

Comment: I can think of this answer only. What you can do is wait for any other guy to answer your question or you can quickly learn a little pathlib :).

Comment: highly appreciated. thanks for your time and let's see if someone can explain to me where my thoughts are in the wrong direction!